# Is that possible to do a keystroke simulate to a website?

Tags: java, javascript, groovy

I came across [typing.io](http://typing.io/) site. It is nice. I was wondering whether I can write a Java/Groovy/Javascript program to simulate the typing process.

Is that possible to do so?

Comment: This kind of question should not be asked on stackoverflow. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to send a keys to any components present on any site, I'd answer:
**Selenium Webdriver** should do the job.

For basic samples see:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Out of your preferences you can implement the solution using java or javascript.

The important method for keys sending itself is then:

```
    WebElement element = ...
    // Enter keys to type on element
    element.sendKeys("Magic!");
```